# How to make an updater for my WPF application? Installing only upgraded files

Tags: c#, wpf

I finished my app and now I want to create a update system. I have the installer so I can install the application in other machines, it was made with InnoSetup (I don't know if it is the best way, but it worked). I know the basics, I have to compare the current version with a string stored in a in a web server, if it is greater, download the files. Now, what files? Because the InnoSetup gives me these files:

[image: Installed app files]

Where are the .xaml (design) files? And the .cs files? Are they compressed in the .exe? For example If I add a few lines to a class, I want to download this class, no the full installer **again**. Because the final size of my application is 30Mb, if I change some things of a class, I do not want the user to have to download the 30Mb again

Comment: In general, do you know what a compiler does?

Comment: This question will be probably closed soon as 'too broad'. You should read more about such things as *.NET assembly*, *.NET runtime*, *compiling and building* and so on.

Comment: @Stefan Sorry, but no. Do you know a website or something where I can learn about compiler does?

Comment: @dymanoid Where can I read about those things that you mentioned?

Comment: You can try looking [here](https://www.google.de/search?&q=.net+compiling+process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most basic of terms, when you compile your program the compiler turns your cs and xaml files into machine readable code and puts it all into an exe file.

Yes, if you add a few lines to a class and recompile it, it will rebuild your exe (assuming the class is part of it, and not an external library).

You still have dependency dll files that you need to include, and any other external content that you've included. But once you have all the external files installed, you wouldn't theoretically need to download them again on an update. Only the files that you've updated, ie the exe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, the dll libraries will not update (unless I have to add more, in this case I should download it). I say this: If my application size is 30Mb and in a little update I want to fix a few lines of code, I don't want to download these 30Mb again, I only want to download the fixed file like any program in the internet, like Steam games, Visual Studio, Photoshop. You understand me?

Comment: Yes, like I said in my answer, you would only make it download the exe. not all the dlls etc.
ps. if this answers your question, remember to hit the checkmark to accept it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The .exe won't increment her size? (a lot, obviously, a bit can increment). Thanks for your answer. Will the .exe not increase in size? (a lot, obviously a bit can increase). Because I have seen that the size of the .exe files of some applications like Discord, Photoshop, Vegas Pro are too big (+100mb), How do those applications to be updated? If every time that they want to upgrade his applications, the users has to download more than 100mb? I don't underestand it

Comment: Yup, photoshop updates are usually quite large downloads. Your CardIndex.exe file is only 3mb.. If you're storing graphics in it, you may consider keeping those in a separate resource to keep the size down.

Comment: Thanks, so the unique way to download updates is redownload the .exe file? There is not other ways?